# How to remove the first 3 latter in string of column in SQL

Tags: sql, pyspark

I have a column with below data and I need to remove latter till'_' and rest part will be saved as another column in sql. Please provide the solution on below requirement

```
BCA_Article_Europ_corona, 
MCCD_Article_Key World,
WSGJ_Article_Yourchoice on pages,
MOL_Article_Rex Newark,
MWBA_Article_Key World,
```

Result should be

```
Article_Europ_corona,
Article_Key World,
Article_Yourchoice on pages,
Article_Rex Newark, 
Article_Key World,
```

Thanks
Ng

Comment: This it depends on what DBMS are you using. What are you working with (oracle, sqlserver...) 
What have you tried so far?

Comment: Thanks.... We are working on pyspark in EMR cluster with using SQLContext libraries to get the result.

Comment: You ask for help in SQL, but solution it depens on which database are you working, may be orable, or mysql, or sqlserver ... each of them may have differents functions to perform the solution. 
Yoy talk about pyspark and this is phyton language, are you sure you need an SQL sentence?

Comment: Yes.... We need the solution in SQL, could you please give the SQL script for this then we will try to convert it as per requirement

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about Spark SQL, but documentation is quite easy to understand. You can get additional info at this url where examples of the different functions available can be found.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/sql/index.html#substr

I suppose somethins like this SQL should work.

Example with direct string

```
SELECT substring('BCA_Article_Europ_corona', instr('BCA_Article_Europ_corona','-')+1)
```

Example with column

```
SELECT substring(yourcolumnhere, instr(yourcolumnhere,'-')+1) from yourtablehere
```

Example with both fields

```
SELECT substring(yourcolumnhere, 1, instr(yourcolumnhere,'-')-1) as PREFIX,
substring(yourcolumnhere, instr(yourcolumnhere,'-')+1) as WITHOUT_PREFIX 
from yourtablehere
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I have more than  3 million data in that column with same format and need to remove till _ and store rest in new column

Comment: Find modified proposed solution! Keep in mind i cannot test it due to I have no pyspark sql installed and I'm writting sql on the fly.